# How to extract DNS records from .cap files

Tags: dns, wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

How can I print the DNS names that were resolved in a tcpdump capture file?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do that is using tshark ( bundled with wireshark ). Something like:

`tshark -nr <your_capture.cap> -Y "dns.flags.response == 0" -T fields -e dns.qry.name -e dns.qry`

Will print all the DNS responses you have in that capture file. You can improve that result by printing only the unique results using:

`tshark -nr <your_capture.cap> -Y "dns.flags.response == 0" -T fields -e dns.qry.name -e dns.qry | sort | uniq`

Or improve a little further by counting the number of times each name appears adding -c to uniq:

`tshark -nr <your_capture.cap> -Y "dns.flags.response == 0" -T fields -e dns.qry.name -e dns.qry | sort | uniq -c`

Will print something like:

```
  2 www.ac-dc.cc
  2 www.acdc.com
  2 www.acdc-discography.com
  2 www.acdcrocks.com
  2 www.albertmusic.com
  2 www.allmusic.com
  2 www.amazon.com
  2 www.apra.com.au
```